# Is there an OSX/macOS CLI command for creating a Finder Alias?

Tags: macos, command-line, finder, alias

For clarification on the ambiguous word *ALIAS* in this question.
While using **Finder** *(of OSX/MacOS)* for generic file operations, and **secondary-clicking on a file or folder**, a pop-up menu *(some refer to these as content-sensitive menu or local menu)* is displayed, showing available operations for that particular file or folder. Among those operations, one called **Make Alias** is what I am talking about.

Is there a unix command for the creation of such an alias *(I refer to these as **Finder Alias**)*? Something I can use in a **Terminal**, or a **shell script**, to generate a similar result of what Finder's Make Alias does.
NOT a symlink. NOT a hard link. A Finder Alias.
If there is no CLI command to create a **Finder Alias**, maybe there is a command to update **WHERE** an existing Finder Alias points **TO**.

---

I found that **AppleScript** can be used to instruct **Finder** to **Make the Alias** for me. And **AppleScript** code can be called from a **shell script** through the **osascript** command. This seems to work fine for all GUI cases, and I am very happy with it.
But I am still interested in creating or modifying a Finder Alias using purely CLI commands, for cases when the job needs to be done via ssh, or when OSX/macOS is booted in a limited environment *(CLI only single-user mode, Recovery mode without Finder, task assigned via Management System which may execute while nobody is logged on and the Mac is just waiting at the Login Window, etc)*.

Knowing details about the structure of a **Finder Alias** file would also be helpful. Such an *Alias* is just a ***file***, after all. I examined a few with **hexdump**. I believe one can be manipulated or created using generic unix tools, if the structure of the file is known.
So far I found no documentation on that. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The always helpful Howard Oakley has a free tool named "alisma" that creates aliases available here: https://eclecticlight.co/taccy-signet-precize-alifix-utiutility-alisma/

From the page:

> alisma is a small command tool which gives access to Finder aliases from Terminal and shell scripts. It has two options, one which creates a Finder alias to a given file/folder, the other which resolves and existing Finder alias to the full path to the file/folder. Now signed, hardened, notarized, and compatible with Catalina.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).